# Athena JDBC Driver 2.0.7 in maven repo?

Tags: maven, amazon-athena

From what I've been able to figure out, the recommended maven dependency for the Amazon Athena JDBC driver is com.syncron.amazonaws, simba-athena-jdbc-driver. The latest version I've been able to find in Maven repo is:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.syncron.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>simba-athena-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) the latest driver version is 2.0.7, which appears to contain some very useful features such as streaming results rather than paging through them.

Is the 2.0.7 version available in maven repository or do I need to download and install it manually?

Comment: The driver you're using is probably not an official Athena driver distribution.

Comment: Hi @PiotrFindeisen can you please share the maven repo link for the official distribution of the  Athena driver distribution. As the above thena JDBC driver is com.syncron.amazonaws, simba-athena-jdbc-driver is no longer available.

PFB the URL  (currently showing 404 from date-  9 Nov 2021 )
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/syncron/amazonaws/simba-athena-jdbc-driver/2.0.2/

Comment: @Swapniljaiswal Bottom line is the driver doesn't appear to be available in maven repo so your best bet is to download and install it manually as described in the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.0.7 is not available in public Maven repos e.g. Maven Central.

I'd download it from [Using Athena with the JDBC Driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) page and install locally with [`mvn install:install-file`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: That's exactly what where I am right now. While this is certainly possible, it's just not the standard way of handling dependencies in the maven world. It really should be in the repo; having an old, outdated version in the repo and not mentioning anything about maven in the documentation is just lazy IMO.

Comment: @marthursson if you work as part of organization I'd consider setting up your own Maven Central local mirror with Nexus or Artifactory. That way you can install the new 3rd party JAR once for everyone in the organization.

Comment: Sure, that would be possible but probably not worth the effort for one single artifact. I do realise there are other benefits of a local mirror, but for our situation it would not be worth it. I ended up downloading the binary and installing it automatically in the root pom with an install-plugin execution.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Karol Dowbecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602555/karol-dowbecki) says, the artifact is not present in the repo at the current time. For anyone else looking for a simple solution (in absence of a local maven mirror): What I ended up doing is downloading the binary, placing it in a `/lib` directory in my source tree and automatically installing it with the install-plugin from the root pom:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install1</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>com.syncron.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>simba-athena-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
                        <version>${athena-driver.version}</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <file>${basedir}/lib/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.7.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: This works... sort of... Is there a way to run this before dependency check? The best I can figure out is to set the phase to ```clean```. But even then, you need to run mvn clean and mvn install independently of each other which is not ideal.